# Using xpath, I can't seem to be able to find a text node

Tags: xpath, web-crawler

So, I am building a web crawler for one site's comment section, and I have came with a problem, it seems I can't find a text node for the comments content. This is how the web pages element looks:

```html
<div class="comments">    // this is the whole comments section
  <div class="comment">   // this is where the p is located
    <div class="comment-top">
      <div class="comment-nr">208. PROTAS</div>
      <div class="comment-info">
        <div class="comment-time">2015-06-30 13:00</div>
        <div class="comment-ip">IP: 178.250.32.165</div>

        <div class="comment-vert1">
          <a href="javascript:comr(24470645,'p')">
            <img src="http://img.lrytas.lt/css2/img/com-good.jpg" alt="">
          </a> <span id="cy_24470645">&nbsp;</span>
        </div>
        <div class="comment-vert2">
          <a href="javascript:comr(24470645,'m')">
            <img src="http://img.lrytas.lt/css2/img/com-bad.jpg" alt="">
          </a> <span id="cn_24470645">&nbsp;</span>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <p class="text-13 no-intend">Test text</p> // I need to get this comments content
  </div>
```

I tried a lot of xpath's like:

```
*/div[contains(@class, "comment")]/p/text()
/p[contains(@class, "text-13 no-intend")]/text()
etc.
```

But can't seem able to locate it.

Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
//div[@class = 'comments']/div[@class = 'comment'][1]/p/text()
```

Comment: You see, using this command I will get every singe comment on the web page. So instead of one comment of "Test text", I will get "Test text", "Test text2", "Test text3", etc. But I need just that one xpath that is universal for the page, so I could group my comments with the corresponding usernames/ip's  and store it in my database.

Comment: It was close, I found out the answer using python. Thanks for the help.